# Why do I see NaN in the minus operator only in Javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, nan

I made a calculator recently and it was working correctly until NaN started showing up when i calculate a result for the minus operator. I was testing the code and it was fine, and then I reloaded the tab and suddenly NaN started showing up in the minus operator. Please tell that why is this happening and how to solve it.

```js
      function btn001() {
        var firstNumber1 = firstNumber.value;
        var operator1 = operator.value;
        var secondNumber1 = secondNumber.value;
        if (operator1 == "-") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1- secondNumber1;
        }
        else if (operator1 == "+") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1+secondNumber1;
        }
        else if (operator1 == "/") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1/secondNumber1;
        }
        else if (operator1 == "*") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1*secondNumber1;
        }
        else if (operator1 == "Ũ") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1*secondNumber1;
        }
        else if (operator1 == "ũ") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + firstNumber1/secondNumber1;
        }
        else  {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Error 414! " + "Invalid Operator or value";
        }
      }
```

```css
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .operator {
        width: 160px;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .button {
        font-size: 40px;
        background-color: white;
      }
      .button:hover {
        font-size: 41px;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      .values {
        height: 60px;
        width: 760px;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .result {
        width: 1300px;
        height: 190px;
        border: 5px solid yellow;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 80px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 90px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Calculate it! </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="firstNumber" placeholder="First value" class="values"> <br>
    <input type="text" id="operator" placeholder="operator" class="operator"><br>
    <input type="number" id="secondNumber" placeholder="Second value" class="values"> <br> <br>
    <button onclick="btn001()" id="submit" class="button"> Calculate Result </button> <br> <br>
    <p id="result" class="result">0</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"=" + firstNumber1` is concatenated before the operation takes place. Add a parenthesis around the oration and convert it o a number before: `"=" + (+firstNumber1- +secondNumber1)`

Comment: Also, use `document.getElementById("firstNumber").value` instead of using named elements directly `firstNumber.value`

Answer (score 1):

The `/` and the `*` operators are working because the variables are converted automatically to int and this operations are executed before the sum.

When you add anything to a string the rest will be converted to a string so just converting them to int won't be enough (since you will have something like `"=" + 10 + 20` witch will be converted in `"=" + "10" + 20 = "=10" + "20"` or if is `-` then will be `"=" + "10" - 20` and `"=10" -  20` is still not a number.

In order to make it work convert numbers and also use parenthesis. so something like:

```
  function btn001() {
    var firstNumber1 = +firstNumber.value;
    var operator1 = operator.value;
    var secondNumber1 = +secondNumber.value;
    if (operator1 == "-") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" + (firstNumber1- secondNumber1);
    }
    else if (operator1 == "+") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "=" (firstNumber1+secondNumber1);
    }
...
```

you can also replace the `+` from
`var firstNumber1 = +firstNumber.value;` and `var secondNumber1 = +secondNumber.value;` with the `parseInt` function (as the other response; it will also work just fine). But you will need the parethesis.